# Laurent series of the function $f(z)=e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ around zero

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

let define :
Laurent series of the function $f(z)=e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ around zero:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}a_n z^n$$

prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ :

$$a_n=a_{-n}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!(n+k)!}.$$

I did the following steps :

$$e^z=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{n!},$$

$$e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{({z+\frac{1}{z}})^n}{n!}.$$

I used the Binomial theorem:

$$\frac{({z+\frac{1}{z}})^n}{n!}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{{{n}\choose{k}}z^k\cdot \frac{1}{z}^{n-k}}{n!}=$$
$$=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{z^{2k-n}}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

So the Laurent series is :

$$e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{z^{2k-n}}{k!(n-k)!}.$$
How to proceed from here ?

Comment: @Ramanujan Any two such annulli give the same series